# Confusion with goroutine

Tags: go

Why does this code output `Let's GoGoGo` instead of the first value assigned to `msg`. I know this has something to do with goroutine. If someone versed with Go could explain it to me concretely I would appreciate it. Here is the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ASywel9KYgs).

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "time"
)

// try to run: go run -race
func main() {
   msg := "Let's Go"
   go func() {
    // Print: "Let's Go"
    fmt.Println(msg)
 }()
  msg = "Let's GoGoGo"
  time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}
```

Comment: You read and modify the `msg` variable from multiple goroutines without synchronization, that's a data race and undefined behavior. You must synchronize access to `msg`.

Comment: Or better yet, just don't share variables between goroutines if you can possibly avoid it.

Comment: @icza how do you synchronize access to primitive data structures like strings

Comment: You program is buggy and may (or may not) output "Let's JavaScript!" or anything else. There is nothing to explain beyond "your code is racy".

Comment: With a [Mutex](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex), for instance. But in this case it would be far simpler to just pass the message as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very simplest answer I can give is that consider the goroutine similar to a process. When you call go func (){...}() it tells the program "Please, start this "process" in the background while I keep executing my program". As you may know, starting a process might take some time. So while it's starting up, the main program keeps executing, outputting "Let's GoGoGo". If you put your sleep before msg = "Let's GoGoGo" you would probably(not at all guaranteed!!) see "Let's Go" printed instead.

I would recommend a book, called "Concurrency in Go" to help you understand how concurrency is done in Go.